# Using a while loop with an and condition to input a number between two values

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to get an input between two numbers in python using a while loop so that it keeps asking the question until both conditions have been met but it keep just skipping past this when i run the code.

```
NumOfStudents=0

while NumOfStudents > 35 and NumOfStudents < 28:
  NumOfStudents = int(input("Please enter the number of students:"))
```

Why doesn't an and work here and what should i use instead?

Comment: A number can't be less than 28 AND greater than 35 at the same time.

Comment: You probably mean to use `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: `or` would work and there is the other option of `while not 28 <= NumOfStudents <= 35:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jhonny Mop, there is no number which is greater than 35 and lower than 28. A simple solution can be like:

```py
while True:
    NumOfStudents = int(input("Please enter the number of students:"))
    if NumOfStudents > 35:
        continue
    elif NumOfStudents < 28:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

You can also do:

```py
NumOfStudents = 0
while NumOfStudents > 35 or NumOfStudents < 28:
    NumOfStudents = int(input("Please enter the number of students:"))
```

Alas, I found out that `start <= x <= end` is a correct syntax. Using python version of `3.7.4` don't know if it works on a different version.

```py
NumOfStudents = 0
while 28 <= NumOfStudents <= 35:
    NumOfStudents = int(input("Please enter the number of students:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work bc your code has no sense. You are asking in the while loop for a number which has to be greater than 35 and lower than 28, that is not possible.

If you wants to make it work, the condition on the while loop should be changed.

Also, if you inicialize the NumOfStudents variable as 0, you will never get into the while loop.

It could work if you do something like this:

```
    NumOfStudents=int(input("Please enter the number of students:"))

    while NumOfStudents < 35 and NumOfStudents > 28:
      NumOfStudents = int(input("Please enter the number of students:"))
```